# Firebase Cloud Messaging not delivering Push Notification on iOS 14

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, push-notification, ios14

Firebase cloud messaging working fine on iOS 13 but after iOS 14 it is not sending the push notification on iOS devices. Working fine for Android devices.

My Code(Nodejs):

```
bodyJSON = JSON.stringify({
      to: deviceId,
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: message,
        badge: count,
        sound: 'default',
      },
      data: {
        chatroom_id: chatroom_id,
      }
    });
```

REST API request for fcm:

```
   request(
     {
       url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': ' application/json',
         Authorization: config.firebaseKey,
       },
       body: bodyJSON,
     },
     function(error, response, body) {
       if (error) {
         console.error(error, response, body);
       } else if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
         console.error(
           'HTTP Error: ' +
             response.statusCode +
             ' - ' +
             response.statusMessage +
             '\n' +
             body,
         );
       } else {
         console.log('Done!');
       }
     },
   );
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Try setting priority: 'high', in bodyJSON object.

Comment: @MohitGupta Thanks for reply, tried but not worked.

Comment: It worked for me,try using the FCM node module,It may help

Comment: If you need I can share the code for fcm node usage

Comment: @MohitGupta Yes Please, it would be very helpful.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ayBk8e get it from here. :)

Comment: @MohitGupta I have tried with fcm node module and I am getting "InvalidServerResponse" error did you know anything about this.

Comment: Try using 'to' instead of registration_ids, actually I was sending notification to multiple users so I used it

Comment: If even that,it don't work,try registering the user again and use new token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223514/discussion-between-mohit-gupta-and-naresh-pawar).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on iOS 14.2beta and without any changes, it is working fine.